# Spring security root authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a simple `WebSecurityConfiguration` configuration class that defines how my application works on a security level.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()

                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .usernameParameter("emailAddress")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()

                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()

                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

}
```

I also have a `@Controller` which defined two simple endpoints

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void testEndpoint() throws CreateException {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

When load up the application and navigate to `localhost:8080/test` I am redirected to the login form as expected. However when I navigate to `localhost:8080/` or `localhost:8080` (no forwardslash) I am shown the "home" page where I would have expected to have been redirected to `localhost:8080/login`.

I have tried changing the `.antMatcher("/**")` to `.antMatcher("**")` but this doesn't have the desired effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that one the `.formLogin()` and `.logout()` they have been ended with a `.permitAll()`. This allowed the root `localhost:8080` to pass through without being authenticated.

By removing them it has solved the issue.